# Getting ComboBox from string

Tags: c#, types, combobox

I want to get a ComboBox from a string, I have 5 ComboBoxes: comboBox1, comboBox2 .. comboBox5. I want to be able to get one of those comboBoxes by giving a method a number(1 to 5). 
What I have:

```
public String getProgNameForFader(int faderNumber)
    {

        Type typeComboBox = Type.GetType("Multichannel_Audio_Mixer_Windows_Forms" + "Form1" + "comboBox" + faderNumber);
        if (typeComboBox != null)
        {
            var comboBox = Activator.CreateInstance(typeComboBox);
            ComboBox theComboBox = (ComboBox)comboBox;
            ..theRest

        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work, typeComboBox is null.
Can someone help?

NVM

Already sorted it out, it was easier to do with a switch statement in my case

Answer (score 0):

Use the assembly-qualified name instead ,`Type.GetType(string)` searches currently executing assembly and `mscorlib` if you don't specify the assembly name in the string.

Comment: 'Type typeComboBox = Type.GetType(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "Form1" + "comboBox" + faderNumber);' Now I have this but it still doesn't get the correct thing